# What is the shape of the shadow of the rim of my lamp shade?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, projection

My lamp has a cylindrical shade and a light bulb sits in the center of it. It projectes the pictured shadow on the wall. That U-shaped curve is the shadow of the rim(s). What shape is it? A parabola?

I know I can "compute" it with some work, but is there a quick geometric answer?

[image]

Comment: Usually, it's a hyperbola: the intersection of a plane with the two branches of the cone.  (Note that the curve above the lamp has a partner below the lamp.)

Comment: Do a search on "Conic Sections", and see what else you can get by moving your lamp around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bulb is more or less a point source, then two cones of light are being emitted from the upper and lower rims of the shade. When the axis of the cylindrical shade is parallel to the plane of the wall, the wall cuts both cones and you get the two opposite sections of an hyperbola.  (See Apollonius, Conics I, 12 & 14). If you incline the top of the lamp toward the wall until light is reaching the wall only from the top of the shade, you have a parabola. Tilting it farther gives an ellipse, and finally a circle.

Comment: Thank you a lot. -- (and everyone else who commented.) I never appreciated (nor liked) the conic sections!! I just never used them anywhere. Now I see how useful they can be :))

Answer (score 1):

Basically without the wall, the light forms a cone that travels upwards (and technically downwards from the bottom of the lampshade. With the wall introduced, though, we are bringing in a vertical plane that is essentially a cross-section of the cone of light from the lamp. Our problem has changed to what is the cross-section of a cone. If we take a vertical cross-section and then take a horizontal cross-section of any point above the "vertex" of the parabola looking shape you see on your wall, we get an image like the following. [A graph of the horizontal cross-section along with the vertical plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47Y6.png). Y is the radius of the cone at that particular horizontal cross-section, but since it is proportional to the height at which you are looking at, we can interchange them without having to worry about our shape changing from a hyperbola to something else. So as we proceed up, y increases linearly. With the Pythagorean theorem, x in the diagram is just $\sqrt{y^2 - 9}$. Squaring both sides gives $x^2 - y^2 = -9$, a graph of a vertical opening hyperbola. Just to be sure, though, we can check to make sure it goes to asymptotes. Solving for y, we get y = $\sqrt{x^2 - 9}$. Let the derivative be S (not formally, just say. When we differentiate, we get $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}$. We can try to take the limit, but we just get infinity divided by infinity. Obviously we have to use L Hospital's rule. Taking the derivative of top and bottom we get $\dfrac{1}{S}$. Note that we would go in an infinite loop if we actually tried to differentiate the bottom. Note that the limit of S as S goes to infinite is what we had to use L Hospital's rule for, but it also happens to be that the limit of $\dfrac{1}{S}$ as  x goes to infinity is the same thing. I believe this is possible, but please correct me if am wrong in saying that the limit of $\dfrac{1}{S}$ as x goes to infinity is the same as the limit of $S$ as x goes to infinity all reciprocated. Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{lim(S)} = lim(s)$, and $lim(s)^2 = 1$ leading to $lim(s) = \pm 1$. This means that the derivative approaches 1 and the picture you see on your wall is a hyperbola as it asymptotes towards a linear graph. Please correct any mistakes I made with my process, as I checked my work on Desmos and the basic graph I used agreed with what I did.

Note that it is highly unlikely that your lampshade shadow's slope actually goes to 1 as the cone I used had the same height as the base radius.